# Change Wordpress Shortcode added in to post

Tags: shortcode, gallery

Problem: I am using a plugin that turns the wordpress gallery into a cool slide show.

How ever, every time I make a gallery - Wordpress add this code to the post .

[gallery ids="334,332"]

I need it to be this -

[wp-slideshow include="334,332"]

---

Might be helpful: 
I think this is the file controlling the output?

http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.0.1/wp-includes/media.php#L745

Comment: Have you considered doing a remove_shortcode( 'gallery' ) and add_shortcode( 'gallery', 'your_function' ) where your_function just calls wp-slideshow either directly or using do_shortcode()

Comment: @MagentaCuda you should write that in a answer. It solves the problem and can be useful for many people.

Comment: One additional thought: As most plugins are designed to work with the gallery shortcode directly, is there not some option setting for your plugin that you are overlooking that allows your plugin to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`remove_shortcode( 'gallery' );
add_shortcode( 'gallery', function( $atts ) {
    $atts = shortcode_atts( array( 'ids' => '' ), $atts );
    return do_shortcode( "[wp-slideshow include=\"$atts[ids]\"]" );
} );`

This may be better than replacing the gallery shortcode as if you decide to change plugin you will have the standard gallery shortcode which many plugins will work with directly.

Comment: If I am reading this right, this simply takes the short code given and changes it at that time of the page loading?

So that the wordpress shortcode stays intact, and latter down the road if needed, I am able to remove this code and that standard gallery show.

Comment: Yes, the [gallery ...] shortcode is actually never changed in the post_content but the gallery shortcode handler is replaced with one that just calls the wp-slideshow shortcode handler instead. I don't think it is a good idea to change the standard gallery shortcode. Also, see next answer for a more efficient way to do this.

Answer (score 0):

@MagentaCuda's solution is the simple solution and should function adequately. However, it does run the [rather complicated shortcode regex](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.8.1/src/wp-includes/shortcodes.php#L211) twice, plus the additional processing of the `do_shortcode()` call. Both should be avoidable.

You don't name the plugin you are using and a search reveals many possibilities that I don't have the time to dig through, so here is an out line and proof of concept code.

The idea is to avoid the second complex shortcode sequence by calling the plugin's shortcode processing function directly.

```
// The callback for the wp-slideshow shortcode
// I don't know the real function name
function plugin_gallery_shortcode( $atts, $content = null ) {
  $atts = shortcode_atts( 
    array( 'include' => '' ), 
    $atts 
  );
  var_dump($atts);
}
add_shortcode('wp-slideshow','plugin_gallery_shortcode');

// This is a callback we are using to hijack the Core gallery
function convert_gallery_shortcode( $atts, $content = null ) {
  $atts = shortcode_atts( 
    array( 'ids' => '' ), 
    $atts 
  );
  $atts['include'] = $atts['ids'];
  unset($atts['ids']);
  plugin_gallery_shortcode($atts,$content);
}
// only hijack if the plugin gallery callback exists
if (function_exists('plugin_gallery_shortcode')) {
  add_shortcode('gallery','convert_gallery_shortcode');
}
```

Comment: Yes, very good ...

Comment: I will try to the this code to work, thanks for a starting point!

<br >

http://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-imageflow2/  This is the plugin I am using